# Why use methods as Newton, ridder or secant method for root finding?

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Why use methods as Newton, ridder or secant method for root finding?

I am bit confused for what reason someone would use these method to determine the root of a function, as it can easily be determined by solving $f(x) = 0$?

Comment: What do you mean "it can easily be determined by $f(x) = 0$"? Do you mean that we can always solve algebraically?  Because that's definitely not true.

Comment: The goal of these methods is to find the $x$ that verify $f(x) = 0$. Show me how easily you find the $x$ that verify $e^x-3x^2+\pi = 0$

Comment: And even solving algebraically doesn't bring numeric approximations. If you want to have approximation values of $\sqrt{2}$, Newton method is valuable.

Comment: "$f(x)=0$" is the _question_, not the _answer_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every equation can be solved without numerical methods.  A few examples of some equations that "look easy" to solve, but can't be solved without numerical methods (at least, not in the way that you're thinking).

- $x^5 - x + 1 = 0$
- $\cos x = x$
- $\tan x = x$
- $e^x = 2x + 2$

Also, we need numerical methods to give us the decimal expansion to the "algebraic" answer, provided such an answer exists.

Comment: I see your point.. Thanks  for pointing it  out :)